# All command line terminals on my PC [Windows 10] run incredibly slow. CMD, Git Bash, VSCode Terminal

Tags: windows, command-line, bash, terminal, git

So, since yesterday, my terminals have been running super slow. Slow to start up and slow to run commands. Running a command takes over one minute. Takes like 5 minutes to start up. At first I thought something was wrong with VSCode, but then I tried using git bash, same thing. Then I tried Windows CMD and it's the same as well.

I've tried restarting my PC, tried changing Windows CMD to legacy mode and tried un-ticking the Quick Edit mode. Googling this has been pretty annoying because any query with "windows" and "slow" just nets me "make your windows faster" results. Even removing Windows from the query, I still get no relevant responses.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try to disable the Antivirus? Some antivirus products can really slow down commandline processes for some obscure reason. Especially Symantec and F-Secure are quite notorious for this. See also the related question (in the list on the right) about  processes being 10x too slow.

Comment: Only use Windows defender. I turned it off but it's the same thing. I will boot into security mode and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Okay, booting into safe mode solves the issue [still persists after coming back to normal boot]. I read somewhere that GPU drivers could have something to do with this, so my next step will be in updating the drivers.

Comment: Well, updating GPU drivers did not work.

Comment: You could restore to a System Restore point from two days ago.

Comment: Did you fix it @Tyranius ?